# How can I reshape my image for a feedforward neural network

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am working on a Covid-19 image classification problem. I have Covid-19 and Normal CXRs images. Now I want to build a Feedforward Neural Network. This code i wrote keeps giving me an error and I am not sure what exactly I am doing wrong.

My `x_train.shape` is `160,256,256,3` while `x_test` is `40,256,256,3`

This is the error I am getting

```
ValueError:
Input 0 of layer "sequential_4" is incompatible with the layer:
expected shape=(None, 196608), found shape=(None, 256, 256, 3)
```

PS I am new to machine learning/deep learning.

This is a snippet of my code

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Flatten, Dense

# Define the architecture of the FNN model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(256,256,3)))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# Compile the FNN model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the FNN model
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

Comment: I suggest you to not do that. Because ffn will not capture image features effectively. Instead use some CNN layers to extract image features then add pooling layer to lower feature size then apply. However, you can use state of the art CNN architectures like ResNet, Deit, or Inception-v3.

Comment: Yeah. I am trying to do the FNN model just for comparison purposes with the CNN

Comment: Your code works already, I tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the flattening layer is expecting the input in a 1D array with 196608 values, the same as 256 X 256 X 3 = 196608.

Using `numpy.reshape()` should work for flattening the image array.
You can do it as follows:

```
# Flatten the image array values in x_train
flattened_x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], -1))
flattened_x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0],-1))
```

You can use these flattened arrays as input to the FNN.